# Streaming PDF made by iTextShap with an HttpHandler sends a corrupted PDF to mobile devices

Tags: asp.net, mobile, itext, httphandler

The following code sends perfect PDF files when the page is opened by a PC, but the PDF file will not work and a message saying "Not a valid PDF" will pop up regardless of the app I am using to open it (Adobe reader, Chrome, etc.) in mobile phones (Android, iOS):

```
public class PdfHttpHandler : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        HttpResponse Response = context.Response;

        string fileName = "somefile.pdf";
        byte[] pdf = GetPDF();

        // stream the pdf
        Response.Buffer = false;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
        Response.BinaryWrite(pdf);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }

    protected byte[] GetPDF()
    {
        var doc = new Document();
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms))
            {
                doc.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4);
                doc.SetMargins(25f, 25f, 20f, 50f);
                doc.Open();

                /***
                     construct the pdf
                ***/

                doc.Close();
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried everything, but still no result. Simply if the page with this handler was opened by a mobile device the file is corrupted. If the file was downloaded in a PC, then sent to a mobile device, it will work fine! this adds to the confusion.

What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**

After converting the handler to a page, it worked fine. So there must be something wrong with the HttpHandler. Still can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Is there any way for you to get the raw bytes of the file from your mobile device to inspect? If not, can you post a sample of your handler's version somewhere we can inspect it? For either it is preferable to not use a service that can render the PDF like Google or Dropbox, we want something that can transport the PDF without interpreting it in anyway, so maybe zip it.

Comment: @ChrisHaas it is an intranet page, and the same exact handler works fine in PCs and in Window phone devices, just not android nor iOS, opening the file that is downloaded in a PC from the same httpHandler in mobile devices works just fine! it's really confusing..

Comment: @ChrisHaas anyway, the code above is the exact handler, except I am removing the pdf constructing part, in case you are interested you can add any line or two then test it...

Comment: There's "it works" and "it looks like its working" and I'm more interested in the latter which is pretty common when dealing with PDFs. The format allows a little flexibility in the binary file itself and you might have some junk data in there that some clients (that happen to be on desktops) are fine with and some clients (that happen to be on mobile devices) complain about. Some clients follow the standard very strictly and some almost appear to make it up as they go along.